# Stuck finding combination differences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am really stuck on a problem regards to finding out if there is difference between two `columns`. `Row value` is a follows:

```
Serial      code
D03L30225   A1
D03L30225   A1
D03L30225   A1
D03L30225   A1
D03L30225   A1
D03L30225   A1
D03L30225   A1
D03L30225   A1
D03L30225   A2
```

so say if there was another entry like A2 at the end , is there a way of knowing combination serial/code difference.

I have tried windows functions like `partition` and `rank` without success

Comment: (1) Edit your question and provide the results you want (the question is not clear).  (2) Do you realize that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets?  There is no ordering to the rows, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: do you want to find the duplicate entries?

Comment: Hi, I want to add a third column and find where there has been a change from the previous one. The third column will in effect be an indicator of a change in the combination of Serial and code columns

Comment: ok. can you show the expected output.

Comment: the expected output can be 1 where this is a change

Comment: where there is no change it can be 0

Comment: As Gordon stated earlier there is no such thing as "previous" in an unordered list, unless there is something else that defines the order, like an id column that you aren't showing in your example?  So the best you can do is to find any [Serial] where it has more than one [code], which is a trivial    SELECT [Serial] FROM [table] GROUP BY [Serial] HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [code]) > 1;

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. One thing to note is that you have to order by something. Perhaps what I have ordered by is not correct for you situation, but you need something there.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Test;

create table #Test
(
    Serial varchar(10),
    code char(2)
)

insert into #Test values ('D03L30225', 'A1')
insert into #Test values ('D03L30225', 'A1')
insert into #Test values ('D03L30225', 'A1')
insert into #Test values ('D03L30225', 'A2')

;
with cte as
(
    select rownum = row_number() over (order by Serial, code), Serial, code
    from #Test
)

select curr.Serial, curr.code,
case
    when curr.code <> prev.code then
        1
    else
        0
end as 'DifferenceFlag'
from cte curr
left join cte prev on prev.rownum = curr.rownum - 1
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher you could use the [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function. We are still on SQL Server 2008 R2. So I needed to do something similar recently I found the method I used above [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/).

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, I assume that you want to add another column `third_column` to your table, and set value for this column according to the change of pair `Serial,Code`

If that's true, you could use this:

```
ALTER TABLE 
    table_name
ADD 
    third_column numeric(18,0);

UPDATE t 
SET t.third_column = t1.rwn
FROM table_name AS t
INNER JOIN 
    (select 
        serial, code
        ,row_number() over (order by serial, code) - 1 as rwn
    from
        table_name 
    group by
        serial, code
    order by 
        serial, code
    ) AS t1 
ON 
    t.serial = t1.serial and t.code = t1.code;
```

Answer (score 0):

I might write the code slightly different.  The first query below will just list those codes having more than one serial number.  And, the second will flag a whole group of codes where within that code are contained multiple serial numbers.

The other solutions provided will give you a proper row number.  In any case, I don't know if this will help, but good luck!

```
select 
code,
count(distinct serial) cnt_serial
from table
group by code
having
count(distinct serial) > 1
```

OR

```
select 
code,
serial,
case when count(distinct serial) over (partition by code) > 1 then 'Y' end fl_code_has_dup
from table
```